# Cd writer not showing in ftab

Tags: 12.04, fstab, cd

Hi I'm using the april edition of ubuntu 12.04

When i try to use my cd it's not detected
 It shows up in disk manager, it is not listed in fstab,when 
i did a checkdisk for devise it gave the following

Detected CD-R drive: /dev/sr0
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'CD-ROM GCR-8523B'
Revision       : '1.02'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc CD-ROM.
wodim: Sorry, no CD/DVD-Recorder or unsupported CD/DVD-Recorder found on this target.

Can anyone tell me what is happening, as everything worked before updating
from 11.10

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Pay no attention to fstab, it isn't supposed to be listed there.

Your drive is only a CD-ROM; it can not write discs.

Comment: Woops ! I have 2 drives one doesn't write but the other does, both show up in the disk manager, when i try to use one or the other, they are not detected.